# How do I get a embedded <object> code working?

Tags: html, object, iframe, video, embedding

I want to embed a video on my page, and this comes in a  code, but when just simply paste this on my page, it won't work. I've done this before with iframes, and this works instantly. How do I get this  code also working?

this is the code

```
<object width="450" height="237"><param name="movie" value="http://www.traileraddict.com/emd/72497"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><embed src="http://www.traileraddict.com/emd/72497" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" width="450" height="237" allowFullScreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is working fine for me. Your code is allright

Comment: Ok try this:

<object data="http://www.traileraddict.com/emd/72497" height="400" width="600"></object>

Comment: Did you checked it in different Browsers ?